# API DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, api, dom-events, addeventlistener, htmlcollection

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>JavaScript API</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Brenen's Pokedex</h1>
  <section>
    <div class="collection-heading">
      <h2>Collection</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="pokedex" class="collection-container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="favorites-heading">
      <h2>Favorites</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="pokedex-two" class="fav-container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
const pokedex = document.querySelector('#pokedex');
const pokedex2 = document.querySelector('#pokedex-two');
const allCards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');


console.log(pokedex);
console.log(pokedex2);
console.log(allCards);

const fetchPokemon = async () => {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=30`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  const pokemon = data.results.map((result, index) => ({
    ...result,
    id: index + 1,
    image: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${index + 1}.png`
  }));
  displayPokemon(pokemon);
};

const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
  const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon.map((monster) =>
    `<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src='${monster.image}'/>
    <h2 class="card-title">${monster.id}.${monster.name}</h2>
  </div>
  `).join('');
  pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};

fetchPokemon();
```

I have built a function using async await to fetch data from an API. Then I would like to try and build an addEventListener function so that I can click on every childnode (div element)(pokemon card) to move from (div parent element) to another (div parent element). I have trouble trying to write out the functionality for the function. Please help!

Comment: Reduce takes two parameters; the callback and the initial parameter.  The callback also takes two parameters.  The carry and the current value.  This is on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Answer (score 1):

As [@Daedalus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785241/daedalus) has mentioned in a comment, you are using `reduce` incorrectly (perhaps `filter` and `map` as well). You could rewrite your function like this to obtain the desired result:

```
function getGreatestDiscoveryYear(data) {
  const occurrences = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.discoveryYear in acc) {
      return { ...acc, [curr.discoveryYear]: acc[curr.discoveryYear] + 1 }
    }
    return { ...acc, [curr.discoveryYear]: 1 }
  }, {})

  const maxOccurrences = Math.max(...Object.values(occurrences))

  return Object.entries(occurrences).filter(([_, value]) => value === maxOccurrences).map(([key]) => key)
}
```

First, you use `reduce` on `data` to get an object which has `discoveryYear` as keys and number of discoveries as values. Then, you need to find which year is the most prevalent - I used `Math.max` to achieve it. Finally, you can print an array of discovery years with the most occurrences (please note that there may be many of them).